# Paperclip - converting images to pyramid tiff after image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip for uploading images via my form.

After the image upload, I would like to run a function which will convert the uploaded images to pyramid tiffs.

My question is how to do activate that function after each image upload.

Many thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Take a look at this asciicast: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images
I think this is what you're looking for. Notice at `after_update`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Used the same concept to do my job. cheers :)